# How to automatically signalize subproperties are updated when base property changed in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, binding

There is a question what I would really want to solve. I did not find good enough answer in the net, so asking there.
The situation is next. For example, I have any ViewModel with one property describing returning any object, second property describing one of this object properties, for example array and third property what returns a value, calculated from second property value. For example, boolean value, what makes it possible to press button if length of array > 0.

The problem is what this is needed this case to update automatically second and third properties if first property was changed, and update third property on second property change.
For now, the best idea I had was to make list of objects describing relations between properties and then on each property update iterate through this list and raise event for each of child properties.

Object, describing property relations

```cs
public class PropertyDependencies
{
    public string PropertyName;
    public string[] ChildProperties;

    public PropertyDependencies(string propertyName, string[] childProperties)
    {
       PropertyName = propertyName;
       ChildProperties = childProperties;
    }
}
```

List of these objects

```cs
List<PropertyDependencies> _dependencies = new List<PropertyDependencies>();
```

Setting up these relations in constructor

```cs
public TreeTaskViewModel()
{
   _dependencies.Add(new PropertyDependencies(
   nameof(SelectedItem),
   new string[]
   {
        nameof(SelectedItemExists),
        nameof(SelectedItemName),
        nameof(SelectedItemDescription),
        nameof(NewTaskCreation)
   }));
   _dependencies.Add(new PropertyDependencies(nameof(NewTaskCreation),
        new string[]
        {
             nameof(TaskCreationButtonText)
        }));
}
```

How it is used:

```cs
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    PropertyDependencies? aim = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < _dependencies.Count; i++)
    {
          if (_dependencies[i].PropertyName == propertyName)
          {
                aim = _dependencies[i];
                break;
          }
    }

    if (aim != null)
    {
          foreach (string childProperty in aim.ChildProperties)
          {
                OnPropertyChanged(childProperty);
          }
    }
}
```

Who used to work with things like that and is there way to solve it in simplier and more optimized way? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just call `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));` to notify about the change of *all* properties.

Comment: Hmm, I did not even know about what this is possible

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the perfect way but i'd trigger the Property Changed event for sub properties from the setter of the parent property, like following:

```
private MyType _ParentProperty;
public MyType ParentProperty
    {
        set { 
             _ParentProperty = value; 
             notif(nameof(ParentProperty)); 
             notif(nameof(SelectedItemExists));
             notif(nameof(SelectedItemName));
             //notify about other sub properties ..
            }
        get { return _ParentProperty; }
    }

public bool SelectedItemExists //this gets notified every time the ParentProperty is assigned
    {
        get { return ParentProperty.Exists; }
    }
public string SelectedItemName //also this
    {
        get { return ParentProperty.Name; }
    }
// other sub properties
```

the notif() function resides in my BaseViewModel which is implemented as following:

```
internal void notif(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for offer. Unfortunately, I already tried do things this way, and the problem is, what if there are multiple layers of dependencies, for example, object->object  field property->computed property based on object field, then I have to signalize about third-layer property change in first property setter, what makes code quite complicated... And the more levels, the worse situation becomes.